# Calculating duration percentages for different day periods using linq

Tags: c#, linq, .net-6.0

I'm working on a project where I need to calculate the reading duration percentages for different day periods based on user reading data. The time periods include dawn, night, evening, morning, and afternoon. I have the start and end times for each reading session, and I want to calculate the total count for each period to determine the distribution of reading sessions **for instance if there are 10 reading sessions and the person reads during 5 of them at dawn, the percentage would be 50%.**

I've already defined the time ranges for each period (e.g., dawn from 4:30am to 5:30am, night from 9pm onwards), and I need help with the logic to calculate the percentages. Additionally, there are cases where a reading session may span multiple periods (e.g., morning and afternoon).

I'm using .NET 6 linq, and any guidance or code snippets on how to approach this calculation would be greatly appreciated.

- I made an attempt to fix the code, but I'm not getting the expected output, particularly for the dawn period.

```cs
private async Task<ProgressDto> GetReadingTimePercentagesAsync()
   { 
            //...

            var readingPeriods = readingSessions 
                                .SelectMany(SplitSessionsIntoPeriods)
                                .ToList();

            var night = readingPeriods.Count(t => t == ReadingSessionPeriod.Night);
            var dawn = readingPeriods.Count(t => t == ReadingSessionPeriod.Dawn);
            var morning = readingPeriods.Count(t => t == ReadingSessionPeriod.Morning);
            var afternoon = readingPeriods.Count(t => t == ReadingSessionPeriod.Afternoon);
            var evening = readingPeriods.Count(t => t == ReadingSessionPeriod.Evening);

            var totalTimes = readingPeriods.Count();

            return new()
            {
                Afternoon = afternoon / (double)totalTimes * 100,
                Dawn = dawn / (double)totalTimes * 100,
                Evening = evening / (double)totalTimes * 100,
                Morning = morning / (double)totalTimes * 100,
                Night = night / (double)totalTimes * 100
            };
   }
```

```cs
 private List<ReadingSessionPeriod> SplitSessionsIntoPeriods(ChallengeKoranReadingProgress session)
  {
            var dawnStart = new TimeSpan(4, 30, 0); //4:30am
            var morningStart = new TimeSpan(5, 30, 0); // 6:30am
            var afternoonStart = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0); // 12pm
            var eveningStart = new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0); // 4pm
            var nightStart = new TimeSpan(19, 0, 0); // 9pm

            var list = new List<ReadingSessionPeriod>();

if (session.StartAt.TimeOfDay >= nightStart)
{
                //spans to the next period 
                if(session.EndAt.TimeOfDay > dawnStart)
                {
                    periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Dawn);
                }

                periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Night);
}
else if(session.StartAt.TimeOfDay >= dawnStart)
{
                if (session.EndAt.TimeOfDay > morningStart)
                {
                    periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Morning);
                }

                periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Dawn);
}
else if(session.StartAt.TimeOfDay >= morningStart)
{
                if (session.EndAt.TimeOfDay > afternoonStart)
                {
                    periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Afternoon);
                }

                periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Morning);
}
else if (session.StartAt.TimeOfDay >= afternoonStart)
{
                if (session.EndAt.TimeOfDay > eveningStart)
                {
                    periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Evening);
                }

                periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Afternoon);
}

return list;
}
```

```cs
public class ReadingSession
{
   public DateTime StartAt {get;set;}
   public DateTime EndAt {get;set;}
}

public enum ReadingSessionPeriod
{
    Night,
    Dawn,
    Morning,
    Afternoon,
    Evening
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 problems in this code:

1. There is duplicate code that appears at the top and bottom of the SplitSessionsIntoPeriods method:

```
    if (session.StartAt.TimeOfDay >= nightStart)
    {
        if (session.EndAt.TimeOfDay > dawnStart)
        {
            periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Dawn);
        }
        periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Night);
    }
```

2. The tests are not properly bounded.

```
if (session.StartAt.TimeOfDay >= nightStart)
{
    //spans to the next period 
    if(session.EndAt.TimeOfDay > dawnStart)
    {
        periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Dawn);
    }

    periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Night);
}
```

should become

```
if (session.StartAt.TimeOfDay >= nightStart || session.StartAt.TimeOfDay < dawnStart)
{
    if (session.EndAt.TimeOfDay >= dawnStart && session.EndAt.TimeOfDay < morningStart)
    {
        list.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Dawn);
    }
    list.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Night);
}
```

And

```
else if(session.StartAt.TimeOfDay >= dawnStart)
{
if (session.EndAt.TimeOfDay > morningStart)
{
periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Morning);
}

periods.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Dawn);
}
```

should become

```
else if (session.StartAt.TimeOfDay >= dawnStart && session.StartAt.TimeOfDay < morningStart) 
{
    if (session.EndAt.TimeOfDay >= morningStart && session.EndAt.TimeOfDay < afternoonStart)
    {
        list.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Morning);
    }
    list.Add(ReadingSessionPeriod.Dawn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My try to solve this problem, check if this is helpful.

I used the logic of clipping the time period into spans, and specifically calculating number of minutes overlapped on each defined period which gives us the weightage of each period,

Averaging is up to us, as we have the weightage for each period.

p.s. the code is not production ready, there are lot of scope for improvements, comments welcomed

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = GetReadingTimePercentage();
        Console.WriteLine("Afternoon :" +result.Afternoon);
        Console.WriteLine("Dawn :" + result.Dawn);
        Console.WriteLine("Evening :" + result.Evening);
        Console.WriteLine("Morning :" + result.Morning);
        Console.WriteLine("Night :" + result.Night);            
    }

    public static ProgressDto GetReadingTimePercentage()
    {
        var readingSessions = new ReadingSession(new DateTime(2023,5,9,0,0,0), new DateTime(2023, 5, 10,23,59,59));

        var readingPeriods = SplitSessionsIntoPeriods(readingSessions);           

        var night = readingPeriods.GetValueOrDefault(ReadingSessionPeriod.Night);
        var dawn = readingPeriods.GetValueOrDefault(ReadingSessionPeriod.Dawn);
        var morning = readingPeriods.GetValueOrDefault(ReadingSessionPeriod.Morning);
        var afternoon = readingPeriods.GetValueOrDefault(ReadingSessionPeriod.Afternoon);
        var evening = readingPeriods.GetValueOrDefault(ReadingSessionPeriod.Evening);

        var totalTimes = readingPeriods.Sum(t => t.Value);

        return new()
        {
            Afternoon = afternoon / (double)totalTimes * 100,
            Dawn = dawn / (double)totalTimes * 100,
            Evening = evening / (double)totalTimes * 100,
            Morning = morning / (double)totalTimes * 100,
            Night = night / (double)totalTimes * 100
        };
    }

    private static Dictionary<ReadingSessionPeriod, double> SplitSessionsIntoPeriods(ReadingSession session)
    {
        var midnight = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
        var daystarts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
        var dawnStart = new TimeSpan(4, 30, 0); //4:30am
        var morningStart = new TimeSpan(5, 30, 0); // 6:30am
        var afternoonStart = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0); // 12pm
        var eveningStart = new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0); // 4pm
        var nightStart = new TimeSpan(19, 0, 0); // 9pm

        var periods = new Dictionary<ReadingSessionPeriod, double>
        {
            { ReadingSessionPeriod.Night, 0 },
            { ReadingSessionPeriod.Dawn, 0 },
            { ReadingSessionPeriod.Morning, 0 },
            { ReadingSessionPeriod.Afternoon, 0 },
            { ReadingSessionPeriod.Evening, 0 }
        };

        foreach (var dates in session.Dates)
        {
            var temp1 = new DateTime(dates.Year, dates.Month, dates.Day).Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0));
            var temp2 = new DateTime(dates.Year, dates.Month, dates.Day).Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59));
            if (dates.Day == session.StartAt.Day)
            {
                temp1 = new DateTime(dates.Year, dates.Month, dates.Day).Add(new TimeSpan(session.StartAt.Hour, session.StartAt.Minute, session.StartAt.Second));
            }
            if (dates.Day == session.EndAt.Day)
            {
                temp2 = new DateTime(dates.Year, dates.Month, dates.Day).Add(new TimeSpan(session.EndAt.Hour, session.EndAt.Minute, session.EndAt.Second));
            }

            double nightDuration1 = ReadingSession.OverlapRange(new ReadingSession(temp1, temp2), new ReadingSession(new DateTime(temp1.Year, temp1.Month, temp1.Day).Add(nightStart), new DateTime(temp1.Year, temp1.Month, temp1.Day).Add(midnight))).Duration.TotalMinutes;
            double nightDuration2 = ReadingSession.OverlapRange(new ReadingSession(temp1, temp2), new ReadingSession(new DateTime(temp1.Year, temp1.Month, temp1.Day).Add(daystarts), new DateTime(temp1.Year, temp1.Month, temp1.Day).Add(dawnStart))).Duration.TotalMinutes;
            double dawnDuration = ReadingSession.OverlapRange(new ReadingSession(temp1, temp2), new ReadingSession(new DateTime(temp1.Year, temp1.Month, temp1.Day).Add(dawnStart), new DateTime(temp1.Year, temp1.Month, temp1.Day).Add(morningStart))).Duration.TotalMinutes;
            double morningDuration = ReadingSession.OverlapRange(new ReadingSession(temp1, temp2), new ReadingSession(new DateTime(temp1.Year, temp1.Month, temp1.Day).Add(morningStart), new DateTime(temp1.Year, temp1.Month, temp1.Day).Add(afternoonStart))).Duration.TotalMinutes;
            double afternoonDuration = ReadingSession.OverlapRange(new ReadingSession(temp1, temp2), new ReadingSession(new DateTime(temp1.Year, temp1.Month, temp1.Day).Add(afternoonStart), new DateTime(temp1.Year, temp1.Month, temp1.Day).Add(eveningStart))).Duration.TotalMinutes;
            double eveningDuration = ReadingSession.OverlapRange(new ReadingSession(temp1, temp2), new ReadingSession(new DateTime(temp1.Year, temp1.Month, temp1.Day).Add(eveningStart), new DateTime(temp1.Year, temp1.Month, temp1.Day).Add(nightStart))).Duration.TotalMinutes;


            periods[ReadingSessionPeriod.Night] = periods[ReadingSessionPeriod.Night] + nightDuration1 + nightDuration2;
            periods[ReadingSessionPeriod.Dawn] = periods[ReadingSessionPeriod.Dawn] + dawnDuration;
            periods[ReadingSessionPeriod.Morning] = periods[ReadingSessionPeriod.Morning] + morningDuration;
            periods[ReadingSessionPeriod.Evening] = periods[ReadingSessionPeriod.Evening] + eveningDuration;
            periods[ReadingSessionPeriod.Afternoon] = periods[ReadingSessionPeriod.Afternoon] + afternoonDuration;

        }


        return periods;
    }



}



public class ReadingSession
{
    public ReadingSession(DateTime startAt, DateTime endAt)
    {
        StartAt = startAt;
        EndAt = endAt;
    }

    public DateTime StartAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndAt { get; set; }

    public IList<DateTime> Dates
    {
        get
        {
            var startDate = StartAt;

            return Enumerable.Range(0, Days)
                .Select(offset => startDate.AddDays(offset))
                .ToList();
        }
    }

    public int Days
    {
        get { return (EndAt - StartAt).Days + 1; }
    }

    public static ReadingSession OverlapRange(ReadingSession source, ReadingSession otherRange)
    {          
        var from = (source.StartAt < otherRange.StartAt) ? otherRange.StartAt : source.StartAt;
        var to = (source.EndAt < otherRange.EndAt) ? source.EndAt : otherRange.EndAt;
        return new ReadingSession(from, to);
    }

    public TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get { return (EndAt - StartAt); }
    }
}


public enum ReadingSessionPeriod
{
    Night,
    Dawn,
    Morning,
    Afternoon,
    Evening
}

public class ProgressDto
{
    public double Afternoon { get; set; }
    public double Night { get; set; }
    public double Dawn { get; set; }
    public double Evening { get; set; }
    public double Morning { get; set; }
}
```